# JSP and servlet does not respond to forwarding

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I'm having some problems with forwarding and where the JSP file refuses to forward even though I'm forwarding : I start from here :

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Web Bank application</th></tr>
</table>

<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Login Page - please enter your Username and Password</legend>
  <form action="loginPage"> 
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password : <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</fieldset>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</body></html>
```

with the screen : 
[image]

Then I move to that JSP file - **adminPage.jsp**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>System Administrator Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Hello ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName} , You've logged in successfully!</h1>
<h1>
Please choose one of the following options
</h1>



<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new manager to the bank system</legend>
  <form action="adminAdds1"> 
    <a href="WEB-INF/results/adminAddNewManager.jsp">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new employee to the bank system</legend>
  <form action="adminAdds2"> 
    <a href="WEB-INF/results/adminAddNewEmployee.jsp">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body></html>
```

with that screen :

[image]

but when I click either one of the two options , and move to `adminAddNewEmployee.jsp` of `adminAddNewManager.jsp` , I get this , over and over again , even though both files are located at the same folder of  `adminPage.jsp`:

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource () is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
```

where the project tree is :

[image]

How can I fix this ? I understand that WEB-INF requires some forwarding , but where do I put the forwarding ? in the JSP ?

but note that I use `href` and it still failing .

Regards

**EDIT:**

in adminPage.jsp is added that :

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Add a new manager to the bank system</legend>
  <form action="adminAdds1"> 
    <a href="src/servlets/Admin1">Press here to continue</a>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

and created a new servlet `Admin1.java` :

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    @WebServlet("/adminAdds1")
    public class Admin1 extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/results/adminPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    }
```

but when I run the all thing again I get :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /WebBank/src/servlets/Admin1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /WebBank/src/servlets/Admin1

description The requested resource (/WebBank/src/servlets/Admin1) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files inside WEB-INF are not directly accessible from client.

**One way** would be change

```
 <a href="SomeServletmapping">
```

Inside SomeServlet get method do

```
request.getDispatacher(yourJSP).forward();
```

**Second way:**

```
move those JSPs outside the WEB-INF folder.
```

Comment: I've updated the post at the end , please take a look. thanks .

Comment: url should be /src/servlets/Admin1 not src/servlets/Admin1. Observe leading slash

Comment: I get the same thing : `type Status report

message /src/servlets/Admin1

description The requested resource (/src/servlets/Admin1) is not available.

`

Comment: I've no such file since I'm using TOMCAT-7 , it just takes care of it without showing it

Comment: Sorry! misread. Update href with this /adminAdds1. Don't need to prefix anything.

Comment: Same thing , nothing's happening : `HTTP Status 404 - /src/servlets/Admin1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /src/servlets/Admin1

description The requested resource (/src/servlets/Admin1) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.28`

Comment: Maybe I'll just take those annoying files outside ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here

```
<a href="WEB-INF/results/adminAddNewEmployee.jsp">Press here to continue</a>
```

According to specification nothing is accessible (`directly`) inside `WEB-INF` folder.

It can be possible to do it using

```
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/path/to/expected.jsp" %>
```

Or dispatching to `JSP` using request dispather or using framework like `Spring`!

Comment: the `include ` doesn't work , I've tried it now and the pages are attached to the page , they are combined within the JSP file , but it still crashes .